# Least residue of $7^5$ modulo $50$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

Find the least residue of $7^5$ modulo $50$ without using a calculator, and using an efficient method. 
So far I have that 
$7=1\pmod{50}$,
$7^5=1^5 \pmod{50}$
Really stuck what to do from here :(

Comment: $7\not\equiv 1\pmod{50}$. If you explain why you think that we might be able to help you better.

Answer (score 3):

$$7^2\equiv-1\pmod{50}$$

$$7^{2n+1}=7(7^2)^n\equiv7(-1)^n\pmod{50}$$